# Using CSS and Span/A tag hooked to a Graphic image to act as a Button

Tags: html, css

Several years ago (read as 10 years) I would use a HTML snippet that would take a SPAN / Anchor tag and hook it to a graphic in shape of a button using CSS. But for some reason I must be missing something as it no longer works.

Example html:

```
<div id="process1" class="loc_1">
<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="columnOne">
            <span class="processTitle"><a href="Example.html">Example</a></span> 
            <span class="updateIndicator">12/28/2014</span> 
       </td>

        <td>
            <div class="loc_1">
                <span class="templateName"><img src="flag.gif" alt="Location 1" />Example Link</span>
                <span class="templateLinks"><a target="_blank" href="Example.doc" class="linkTemplate"></a></span>
            </div>
        </td>

     </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Associated CSS:

```
div span.templateName{
  float: left;
  width: 270px;
  height:auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:7px;
  overflow:visible;
}
div span.templateLinks {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:7px;
}

div span.templateLinks a.linkTemplate{
  float: left;
  width:45px;
  background:transparent url("button.gif") 0px 0px no-repeat;
}

div span.templateLinks a.linkTemplate:hover{
    background:transparent url("button_over.gif") 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

Specifically, the "span class="templateLinks"..." section does not render the graphic button. Everything else renders as normal, and no errors or warning are generated.

Thoughts or comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh! Thank you Nickfmc!

The key was the height:

```
div span.templateLinks a.linkTemplate{
  float: left;
  height:28px;
  width:45px;
  background:transparent url("button.gif") 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

I swear I tried the height parameter multiple ways in the CSS without success, yet simply adding it within the SPAN tag works. Something so simple yet a pain when it work previously.

Thank goodness for the this forum!

Answer (score 0):

add the height of the button to the  `div span.templateLinks a.linkTemplate`

Comment: Are you saying that the div span.templateLinks wouldn't inherit the height from the span.templateName even though it is inline? I tried removing the float:left, and inserting a height: 28px into the div span.templateLinks and could see no change.

Comment: you should provide a fiddle, its hard for people to troubleshoot when images are involved and no example is provided.  For all we know flag.gif is 2px tall

Comment: Unfortunately, this board generates and error that indicates I need to have at least 10 postings to include an image file, which unfortunately I do not have. That said, the flag gif is 25 by 15 pixels as an example.

Comment: you need to put the height of the button.gif on div span.templateLinks a.linkTemplate see http://jsfiddle.net/joa05253/